# Избыточно ли словосочетание «целенаправленно в направлении»?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Избыточно ли сочетание «целенаправленно в направлении» в данном предложении?

> Различия в применении этих приемов указанными субъектами состоят в том, что сотрудники действуют более  целенаправленно в направлении имеющейся у них доказательственной информации и решают при этом свои специфические задачи

Answer (score 1):

Да,конечно, речевой недочет здесь есть. Не рекомендуется рядом употреблять однокоренные слова (целенаправленно в направлении). Но это не смысловая избыточность. Смысл предложения не очень ясен. чтобы исправить  верно. Может, так: «Различия в применении этих приемов указанными субъектами состоят в том, что сотрудники действуют более целенаправленно *в части*  имеющейся у них доказательственной информации и решают при этом свои специфические задачи»?

Answer (score 1):

По смыслу избыточности нет: "Целенаправленно" -- значит, имея четкую цель. Это характер действия. "В направлении ..." -- указание на направление, по всей вероятности, на ту самую четкую цель. Характер действия и его направление -- не одно и то же.

Однако в приведенной формулировке это звучит как "действуют направленно на цель в направлении ...". Чтобы избавиться от этого, можно написать "действуют целенаправленно, имея целью ..." или "действуют четко в направлении ..."

P.S. "Действовать в направлении информации" -- неграмотно. Возможно, имелось в виду "действовать, исходя из информации".